# How to force errors in R paragraphs to be reported as Zeppelin paragraph errors?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

We are using [Zeppelin 0.8.0](http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/).
When running all paragraphs in a note, we expect Zeppelin to stop at the first paragraph where an error occurred. Unfortunately, we found that this is not the case with the `%spark.r` interpreter: i.e., errors are printed but effectively ignored.

Here is an example of this using the `%spark` interpreter where an error occurred in the execution of the 2nd paragraph (`1/0`); consequently, Zeppelin shows the status of this paragraph as error and does not execute the 3rd paragraph (`1+1`) at all.

[image: Detected paragraph error]

Now, lookat this example using the `%spark.r` interpreter where an error occurred in the execution of the 2nd paragraph (`1 + "foo"`). The interpreter prints the error; however, this error is not reported at the level of the interpreter per se and the paragraph status shows "FINISHED" as if execution was error-free. Consequently, Zeppelin continues executing the 3rd paragraph.

How can we force any error that occurs in the execution of a `%spark.r` paragraph to be reported as an "ERROR" of the paragraph itself, thereby preventing the execution of subsequent paragraphs when we invoke on "Run All Paragraphs"?

[image]

Comment: This is a known bug of sparkr interpreter in zeppelin. https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3167

Comment: Thank you; I searched but couldn't find a known bug about this.